# Localizing Xib brings strange troubles

Tags: objective-c, localization, xcode4, ios4

I have an app (iPhone) with 2 Xibs that I would like to localize, but only for one Nib that has some labels to translate directly in IB. This seemed really easy until I built.

-1) The simulator suddenly did not load any of my backgrounds (UIImageViews, the same for both xib's, and programmatically modified at runtime). I did NOT change anything around this! tried delete/clean/add again, nothing changed. (debugger says it could not load the image referenced from a nib, though i changed no references an as i will say, it works on the real device)

-2) Simulator crashes (every time) and sends a report to Apple as I try to relaunch the app after modifying languages in the settings panel. As I re-build, the app runs again, the correct xibs are loaded. [edit: this happens no more if I stop tasks in Xcode, so is probably not really a bug]

-3) In the device, no crash, images are OK on background, but the english xib is loaded only.

I just can't make my way through this inconsistent behavior. Bumping my head on the wall did not solve the problem...

Comment: Did you use the `genstrings` or `ibtool` tools to generate strings files? Did you clean up (perhaps even manually an `rm -Rf projectdir` in the DerivedData directory? Sometimes cached localization files cause issues. Did you try to manually remove the app from the simulator and reinstall (Build & Run)?

Comment: I did not use genstrings nor ibtools (.xib was modified manually). I did clean, removed and re-added my png-24 files, removed from the simulators... just like if the image files were not there... but they are, and visible when i click on it in xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tired of not finding any solution. It has to be an Xcode bug. I copied my code and recreated the app in a new project. Everything works fine but nothing changed in the content, not even a single space!
Thxs for those who took the time.